# Is there an event to watch for on pushObject?

Tags: jquery-ui, ember.js

I'm programmatically pushing an object (using pushObject) into a list that is sortable.  My problem becomes that if I try `$(selector).sortable('refresh')` or `$(selector).sortable('serialize')` the serialize doesn't contain the recently added dom item.  I can console.log($(selector)) and it seems to know that the dom item has been added though.

My original thought is there an event to watch for once pushObject has finished?  Or a callback?

Comment: can you show the code of your controller or where ever you call pushObject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there an event to watch for on pushObject?

Easiest way to do this is add an observer that fires when the list length has changed. But probably that's not gonna be enough in this case.

It sounds like this is a timing issue. If you try to call refresh right after pushObject (or even in an observer) the refresh code is going to run before the dom has been updated.

The trick is to make sure you are calling `$(selector).sortable('refresh')` after the new elements have been written to the dom. That could be from a didInsertElement hook on the dom item's view or from an observer, but as @Luke reminded me in comments best way to do it is by scheduling refresh to run after render has completed. Something like:

```
Em.run.schedule('afterRender', this, this.refreshSortable)
```

Comment: you're completely right.  I used the addEnumerableObserver method, and it fires before the DOM has been updated.  I'm going to look into didInsertElement or parentViewDidChange.  Will update once I find a solution

Comment: You can also schedule a method to run after rendering is complete. e.g. `this.pushObject(...); Em.run.schedule('afterRender', this, this.refreshSortable)`

Comment: @LukeMelia thanks I always forget about that one, it's def the way to go.

Comment: thanks Mike and Luke, you guys are awesome.  Marked as answer